# Error: unexpected symbol in: R error message

Tags: r, forcats

I am using the data set 'csew', and trying to collapse the variable 'fairatt7' within my data set to just two levels: Agree and Disagree

If I write these codes out individually, it does one but reverses the other. I know I need to collapse them both at the same time, in the same code, so I write:

```
csew$fairatt7_rc <- fct_collapse(csew$fairatt7, "Disagree" = c("Strongly disagree", "Tend to disagree"), "Agree" = c("Strongly agree", "Tend to agree")
```

The error message I receive is:

> Error: unexpected symbol in: "csew$fairatt7_rc <-
>   fct_collapse(csew$fairatt7, "Disagree" = c("Strongly disagree", "Tend
>   to disagree"), "Agree" = c("Strongly agree", "Tend to agree") levels"

What does this mean? Can you please advise how I can change my code so that all four levels are collapsed into just two?

Comment: looks like a `)` is missing at the end. "unexpected symbol" usually means a missing symbol such as a parenthesis, a comma, ...

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example with a subset from your dataframe may be useful but it looks like a closing parenthesis is missing.
It is possible the error occurs because R starts reading the following line.